# ¿Cómo muestro una ventana con un PDF sin salir de la página con html?

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Estoy en una página y mediante un `href` me manda a otra página que en realidad es un PDF construido con PHP, pero lo que quiero es que al darle click al link me muestres una ventana en la misma página y ahí el pdf sin salir de la página pero que muestre en una ventana q no pertenezca a la página. Es decir eso de `_self`  o `_top` no me sirve porque es cierto me abre en la misma pagina pero yo quiero que salga una ventana en la misma página y ahí se muestre.

Espero que me puedan ayudar les pongo el codigo de esa parte:

```
  while($fila = pg_fetch_object($resultado))
  {
        $contador++;
        $bgcolor="#FF9999";

        $link = "<a href='listas/indexpdf.php?nserie=$fila->serie&guia=$fila->nroguia&fretorno=$fila->fecretorno&fecsalida=$fila->f_salida' target='_blank'  ><img src='img/adobe.gif'        style='cursor:pointer'></a>";

    ?>
 <tr > 

       <td  style=" background-color:#CCE2FE" type="ro"><?=$contador?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="left"><?=$link?></td>
       <td  type="ro"><?=$fila->serie?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->nroguia?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->estado?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->codigo?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->mensajero?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->f_salida?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->total?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->entregados?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->motivos?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->reenvios?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->anulados?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->perdidos?></td> 
       <td type="ro" align="right"><?=$fila->ruta?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->tipo_pago?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->cod_zona?></td>
       <td type="ro" align="center"><?=$fila->fecretorno?></td>

    </tr>
    <?  
    }
    ?>
  </table>
```

Comment: Lo que queres que sea un popup??

Comment: Parece que lo que quieres es un modal. Estás usando jQuery (aunque una versión realmente vieja) por lo que podrías buscar un plugin si quieres facilitarte la tarea. Si no, siempre podrías crear tu propio modal básico que contenga un `iframe` al PDF

Comment: Yo no usaría window.open (muchos navegadores ya bloquean). Quizás lo mejor es lo que dice Álvaro. Usa un div, hazlo modal y carga dentro un iframe con el PDF. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Display-PDF-File-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-Window.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Mal redactada la pregunta, segun lo que entendi es que quieres que mediante un `<a href>` se habra una ventana flotante, o sea popup pero en el codigo de ejemplo solo usas `<button>` de todas formas respondere tu pregunta sin tener en cuenta el codigo que envias:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('document.php','mywindowtitle','width=500,height=150')">open window</a>
```

Comment: DISCULAPA me confundi de codigo ya lo edite